# Scrapy - item processing over multiple pages

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy

I need to scrape the Brand, model and edition of vehicles over multiple pages and place it into a single item. I want my spider to retrieve a list of vehicle brands from page1. Then for each brand go to page2 and get all the models. For each model go to page3 and get all the associated editions and specifications. 
Each edition with it's brand and model needs to be placed into a single car item (and yielded?). 
Unfortunately it's only looping through all steps for the first brand on page1. How do I force it to loop over all models and associated editions before getting the next brand and starting the process over? I've seen this question asked in different variations, but I´m still having a hard time understanding how multiple callbacks work when I´m trying to control the order of processing into one item.

```
class Spider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "fdm_bot"
    allowed_domains = ["fdm.dk"]
    start_urls = ["http://www.fdm.dk/bildatabasen",]

    def parse(self, response):
        rows = response.xpath('//td//a[contains(@href,"bildatabasen")]')
        for row in rows:
            car = CarItem()
            car['brand'] = row.xpath('./text()').extract()
            absolute_URL = response.urljoin(row.xpath('./@href').extract()[0])
            request =  Request(absolute_URL, callback=self.parse_model, meta={'car':car})
            yield request

    def parse_model(self, response):
        rows = response.xpath('//td//a[contains(@href,"bildatabasen")]')
        for row in rows:
            car = response.meta['car']
            brand = car['brand'][0]
            model = row.xpath('./text()').extract()[0]
            car['model'] = string.replace(model,brand, "")
            absolute_URL = response.urljoin(row.xpath('./@href').extract()[0])
            request =  Request(absolute_URL, callback=self.parse_editions, meta={'car':car})
            return request

    def parse_editions(self, response):
        rows = response.xpath('//td//a[contains(@href,"bildatabasen")]')
        for row in rows:
            car = response.meta['car']
            brand = car['brand'][0]
            model = car['model']
            edition = row.xpath('./text()').extract()[0]
            edition = string.replace(edition,brand, "")
            car['edition'] = string.replace(edition,model, "")
            absolute_URL = response.urljoin(row.xpath('./@href').extract()[0])
            request = Request(absolute_URL, callback=self.parse_specs, meta={'car':car})
            return request

    def parse_specs(self, response):
        car = response.meta['car']
        car['engineVolume'] = 1.0
        return car
```